# How can I change the express static path based on the route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to change the static path based on the route. For example (not working):

```
const app = express();
const appRouter = express.Router();
const adminRouter = express.Router();

appRouter.use(express.static('/path/to/app/static/assets');
adminRouter.use(express.static('/path/to/admin/static/assets');

app.use('/', appRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
```

This also does not work:

```
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('/path/to/app/static/assets');
app.use('/admin', express.static('/path/to/admin/static/assets');
```

What I **do not** want to do is set both paths as static for the entire app:

```
// the following will expose both paths as static for the entire app
// this does not accomplish what I am trying to do

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('/path/to/app/static/assets');
app.use(express.static('/path/to/admin/static/assets');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution following the git issue posted by Tolsee. I [published it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-dynamic-static) to npm under the name `express-dynamic-static`.

Here is quick example of how to use it:

```
const express = require('express');
const dynamicStatic = require('express-dynamic-static')(); // immediate initialization
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(dynamicStatic);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    dynamicStatic.setPath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/app/assets'));

    // res.render...
}


app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    dynamicStatic.setPath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/admin/assets'));

    // res.render...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is not possible from your approach with `express.static()`. Your #2 approach does create virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the express.static function. Follow [this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for more info.

But what seems can be done is changing the path of `express.static()` in run time. Please follow through [this git issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3165). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible with Express static middleware.